# (PHP/Zend) Fatal error: Class 'fooClass' not found in /foo/path

Tags: php, zend-framework, models, bootstrapping

**SOLVED - Scroll down**

I'm trying to use a Zend_Db_Table model subclass in Zend 1.11.11. I've the model class in models folder:

```
<?php

class fooTable extends Zend_Db_Table {

    protected $_name = 'foo';
    protected $_primary = 'id';

}
```

And in the bootstrap.php I've written the following code:

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    public function _initAutoloader()
    {

        $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath'    => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace' => 'Application'
        ));

        return $autoloader;
    }
}
```

When I declare a fooTable object I get the Fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'fooTable' not found in /foo/path/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 13
```

But if I declare the class fooTable into the IndexController all works fine. Anyone has some ideas how to fix that?

### Solution

I fixed that in a simply way:

- Called the file Modal_Foo.php;
- Changed the class name in AppNamespace_Modal_Foo; Into the IndexController declare it as new
- AppNamespace_Modal_Foo;

I hope that this would helps someone :)

Comment: Don't know, where to start, thus I just recommend ZFs own quickstart.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an autoloading issue.

You can autoload your model either in the bootstrap or in the application.ini by autoloading the namespace.